# A format string to put % after a number

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out how to append a % to a number.  The number length varies so that's what I'm not sure about..how to create a regex that takes whatever the digit is and appends % to it.

I was thinking this but how would you handle the unexpected length?

```
"\\%d{DigitlegnthVariesHere}"
```

or is it something as simple as `"\\%d"`

Comment: post error, I meant "after" the value.  Sorry for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how to put a `%` after each *(whole)* number in a string *(edit: see fractional numbers below)*:

```
//                              In the "search for" regular expression:
//             +--------------- \d means "any digit"
//             | +------------- +  means "one or more of the previous thing"
//             | | +----------- The 'g' flag means "globally" in the string
//             | | |            --------------------------
//             | | |            In the replacement string:
//             | | |   +------- $& means "the text that matched"
//             | | |   | +----- % isn't special here, it's just a literal % sign
//             | | |   | |
//             V V V   V V
s = s.replace(/\d+/g, "$&%");
```

Example:

```
var s = "testing 123 testing 456";
s = s.replace(/\d+/g, "$&%");
console.log(s); // "testing 123% testing 456%"
```

---

In a comment below, you said:

> problem if you enter a decimal like 47.56, it'll output 45% 56%

Quite true, because `\d` is just for digits, it doesn't magically include a `.`.

To handle fractional numbers requires a slightly more sophisticated expression:

```
//                                    In the "search for" regular expression:
//             +--------------------- \d means "any digit"
//             | +------------------- +  means "one or more of the previous thing"
//             | |+------------------ (?:....) is a non-capturing group (more below)
//             | ||  +--------------- \. is a literal "."
//             | ||  | +------------- \d means "any digit" again
//             | ||  | |   +--------- ? means "zero or one of the previous thing,"
//             | ||  | |   |          which in this case is the non-capturing group
//             | ||  | |   |          containing (or not) the dot plus more digits
//             | ||  | |   | +------- The 'g' flag means "globally" in the string
//             | ||  | |   | |        --------------------------
//             | ||  | |   | |        In the replacement string:
//             | ||  | |   | |   +--- $& means "the text that matched"
//             | ||  | |   | |   | +- % isn't special here, it's just a literal % sign
//             | ||  | |   | |   | |
//             V VV  V V   V V   V V
s = s.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g, "$&%");
```

So basically what that says is: Match a series of digits *optionally* followed by a decimal point and more digits, and replace them with the matched characters plus a `%`.

Example:

```
var s = "testing 123.67 testing 456. And then...";
s = s.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g, "$&%");
console.log(s); // "testing 123.67% testing 456%. And then..."
```

Note how even though the `456` was followed by a `.`, because it didn't have more digits immediately after it, we didn't inappropriately add a `%` after the `.`.

---

At one point your question said "in front of" the number rather than after. If you really wanted it in *front* of the number, just move the `%` before the `$&`:

```
str = str.replace(/\d+/g, "%$&");
```

Comment: to explain, `+` means "one or more of the previous". it's slightly more restrictive than `*`, which means "zero or more of the previous"

Comment: Quote: `append '%' IN FRONT OF a number` (capitals mine). Good answer though. (And I am aware `append in front` is technically incorrect.)

Comment: @11684 it is, but most people say "prepend"

Comment: I agree with you, but `in front of` should have hinted the OP meant 'prepend'. @sgroves

Comment: @11684 But what's it matter? It doesn't hurt - it's better to be safe and provide both options when it's not **100%** clear what the OP wants. T.J. explained both, so it's up to the OP to use which they actually meant.

Comment: @11684: I could have sworn the text didn't have "in front of" in the first version. Either I just missed it, or it was a ninja-edit. :-)

Comment: doesn't string.replace expect a string as the first param?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: No (you could just try what I showed you above in the console of your browser). You can give `String#replace` a string *or* a regular expression. If you give it just a string, it will only replace the first match, and of course you can't do fancy things like match digits. It matches the exact string you give it.

Comment: tried using this this this.value = strValue.replace("/\\d+/g", "$&%");

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Again: Try what I actually gave you above. It's not pseudocode, it's real code. `this.value = strValue.replace("/\\d+/g", "$&%");` won't work because you don't want any `"` around the regular expression (putting `"` around it makes it a string, and so `replace` looks for *exactly* what you have in the quotes), and you don't put two backslashes in. (If you're used to Java rather than JavaScript, one key difference is that JavaScript has regular expression literals, you don't use strings like you do with Java.)

Comment: this is exactly what I tried, it did nothing                 var strValue = String(inputValue);
                this.value = strValue.replace(/\\d+/g, "$&%");

Comment: fyi I'm using Dojo if that helps any.

Comment: it's working something with dojo doesn't show the % even though the text has %

Comment: problem if you enter a decimal like 47.56, it'll output 45% 56%

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Ah, now that requires a slightly complex expression, see the edit.

Comment: trying it now thanks much especially for explaining, I need to practice regex more\